# Emojis not correctly encode into hexadecimal

Tags: php, unicode, encoding, hex, emoji

```
$message = "Spanish Language 
á, é, í, ó, ú, ñ, ü
       ";
$hex = '@U' . strtoupper(bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding($message, 'UCS-2','auto')));
```

When I send $hex into the following API all things are fine except the emojis, instead if emojis `?` symbol appears in the mobile

https://api.txtlocal.com/docs/encodingdecodingunicode

please correct me what I m doing wrong.

Comment: `UCS-2` is required?

Comment: not 100% sure, just following the documentation example, I tried with UCS-4 but same issue

Comment: What if you use `mb_convert_encoding($message, 'UTF-8','auto')`?

Comment: I tried with UTF-8 but I received empty message

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed this issue, just change following the line of code

`return '@U' . strtoupper(bin2hex(mb_convert_encoding($message, 'UTF-16','UTF-8')));`

Answer (score 2):

These emoji are not representable in UCS-2. In UTF-16, they are represented using surrogate pairs, which are not supported in UCS-2. For example,  is encoded in UTF-16 as this:

```
0x3d 0xd8 0x0b 0xde
```

This is four bytes, even though it is supposedly only a single character. UCS-2 guarantees that all characters it contains will be take exactly two bytes, and so  is not included.

Comment: what I change in my code for supporting these emojis?

Comment: check this URL http://chadselph.github.io/smssplit/ seems UCS-2 supporting